# Perform Function With Arguments From String

Tags: javascript, function, eval

String is as follows: `"foo('argument1','argument2')"`

How can I execute this function as javascript without using `eval`?  I know you can use

`window[func](arguments)`,

but the arguments are part of the string.  I tried using regex but I'm not sure how to do it considering javascript doesn't have lookbehinds.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to do this? From what you have said, `eval` is your only real option, but more info would help.

Comment: One should ask, how is this string being made in the first place? and can't you construct something more helpful there, instead (e.g. JSON)

Comment: If you can convert the arguments to an array, you can use `window[func].apply(null, args)`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Did you notice that your comment was part of my answer ?

Comment: @dystroy: I just did! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing it, one has already been given by dystroy.

A slightly simpler way would be this:

```
var args = "foo('argument1','argument2')".split(/[()',]+/).slice(0,-1)
Function.prototype.call.apply(window[args[0]],args)
```

Comment: I like this.  Very very nice.

Comment: Did you realize the main reason it's shorter is that it only handles strings ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
var s = "foo('argument1','argument2', 5, true)";
var m = s.match(/([^(]+)\(([^)]+)\)/);
if (m) {
   var f = window[m[1]];
   var args = m[2].split(',').map(function(v){
     return JSON.parse(v.trim().replace(/^'/,'"').replace(/'$/,'"'))
   });
   f.apply(null,args);
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/esabev/2/edit) (open the console)

Note that this works only for primitive arguments. If you want to handle other types of arguments without eval, you'd better define what types you want to handle.

Comment: If some part of my answer isn't clear, please ask and I'll explain.

Comment: It's clear.  The purpose is so I can have an inline custom event (ie: `<button onmyevent="dothis('argument1')">Button</button>`).  I use jQuery to tell the event to fire, but I needed a way to execute the string given by the `onmyevent` attribute.